# How do I block url in Ubuntu internet shared connection?

Tags: ubuntu, internet

Basically I want to administrate the internet shared connection that I make in Ubuntu 10.4. Anyone knows how? I turn on a Firewall but only blocks certain applications.

Comment: Easiest is probably to use a proxy like Squid and force all web traffic through your proxy.

Comment: @salmod but i have to make anything in the client computer?

Comment: The [TLDP Transparent Proxying with Squid HOWTO](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy-2.html) is a little old, but should be useful.

Comment: @sarnold ok i will try with this option; i just want to administrate complete the internet flow in my enterprise many people spend too many time in youtube, and this kill my internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this link will provide you neccessary help for you: [How to Block an IP Address From Attempting a Connection to Ubuntu](http://www.ehow.com/how_8400037_block-address-attempting-connection-ubuntu.html):

> - Click "Applications" on the Ubuntu dashboard, then click "Accessories" or "See More Results," and click "Terminal." A terminal
>     command prompt window will appear.
> - Type "sudo ufw default allow" at the command prompt, and press "Enter." Type the root password on the command line if prompted. Type
>     "sudo ufw enable" at the command prompt, and press "Enter." Type the
>     root password on the command line if prompted.
> - Type "sudo ufw deny from x.x.x.x" at the command prompt, except replace the "x.x.x.x" with the IP address you wish to block. Press
>     "Enter."